# Android how to make fading edges appear on Horizontal List View

Tags: android

I have used [HorizontalListView](https://github.com/dinocore1/DevsmartLib-Android/blob/master/devsmartlib/src/com/devsmart/android/ui/HorizontalListView.java) which does the functioning of `ListView` but in horizontal manner. This [HorizontalListView](https://github.com/dinocore1/DevsmartLib-Android/blob/master/devsmartlib/src/com/devsmart/android/ui/HorizontalListView.java) doesn't show `fadingEdge` on scroll to first and last items of the list.So I need to add `fadingEdge` on this view.I may find the scroll of first and last child,but I don't have any idea on how to show `fadingEdge` when scroll reaches to first and last child as done in `ListView`.Further I have already added

```
      <com.ui.widgets.HorizontalListView
        android:id="@+id/horizontalListView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dip"
        android:gravity="left" 
        android:fadingEdge="horizontal"/>
```

And it doesn't have any effect.So could you point me in the right direction on how to programmatically add `fadingEdge` to the `HorizontalListView`

Answer (score 2):

From [the documentation for `fadingEdge`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#fadingEdge):

> This attribute is deprecated and will be ignored as of API level 14 (`ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH`). Using fading edges may introduce noticeable performance degradations and should be used only when required by the application's visual design. To request fading edges with API level 14 and above, use the `android:requiresFadingEdge` attribute instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `android:overScrollMode` attribute.

Just add

```
android:overScrollMode="always"
```

to your View.

> android:overScrollMode can have three values: "always", "never", "ifContentScrolls".